# Avoid Jackson changing time

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have a dto mapped like this:

```
 private Date startDate;
```

When my frontend call the endpoint, Jackson  uses the Timezone and It changes the time of the date.

For example:
Frontend
`startDate: 1618246637113`
which represents  *Date Mon Apr 12 2021 **17:57**:17 GMT+0100* will change to *Mon Apr 12 **18:57**:17 CEST 2021*

How can I avoid that? I need that the time should remains 17.57 (in the example)

Comment: 1618246637113 is a timestamp without any timezone. There are no information which server can use to define client's timezone. To get the desired result you will need to store each client's timezone and cast timestamp to it or change the format of the startDate.

Comment: I tried to pass a different date format which is including the timezone, for example: "2021-04-12T08:05:00.000+01:00" but the problem is still there, the backend will convert the time to 9:05.   I use the browser with timezone Dublin and the backend on Europe/Rome

Comment: As a second part of the solution you can use ZonedDateTime as startDate type.